# Find a value in "look up" list that are similar but not equal without nested for loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested, lookup

I have 2 lists. 1 list contains a set of columns, and the other list is a "look up" of those columns.

I run a code to check if some columns are present in a list if they are not, I return the missing columns:
Missing column

`cols_diff = ['VendorPartNumber']`

My look up list looks like this:

```
table_cols_lookup = ['[Asset] NVARCHAR(MAX)', ' [SKU] NVARCHAR(MAX)', ' [BreakFix] NVARCHAR(MAX)', ' [Carrier] NVARCHAR(MAX)', ' [Created] NVARCHAR(MAX)', ' [CreatedBy] NVARCHAR(MAX)', ' [Code] NVARCHAR(MAX)', ' [Full] NVARCHAR(MAX)', ' [IsItem] NVARCHAR(MAX)', ' [LNumber] NVARCHAR(MAX)', ' [OrderedQuantity] NVARCHAR(MAX)', ' [OrderIntent] NVARCHAR(MAX)', ' [OrderNumber] NVARCHAR(MAX)', ' [OrderType] NVARCHAR(MAX)', ' [ReceivedLocation] NVARCHAR(MAX)', ' [ReceivedQuantity] NVARCHAR(MAX)', ' [RemainingQuantity] NVARCHAR(MAX)', ' [SerialNumber] NVARCHAR(MAX)', ' [SKUId] NVARCHAR(MAX)', ' [SkuName] NVARCHAR(MAX)', ' [Supplier] NVARCHAR(MAX)', ' [VendorPartNumber] NVARCHAR(MAX)']
```

Now, I have a code that works, but it is using nested for loops and I'm not sure how efficient it is when the number of cols grows from a couple of 10s,20s cols to 500+ columns.

```
for col in table_cols_lookup:
    for dcol in cols_diff: 
        if dcol in col:
            print(col)
```

it returns the following, which is the column that I would use to add the missing column to a SQL DB

`[VendorPartNumber] NVARCHAR(MAX)`

Any ideas of how to make the lookup more efficient? avoid nested for loops if possible?

Comment: You can make the code more efficient by using a list comprehension and the any function to remove the nested for loop. Here's the modified version:

for col in table_cols_lookup:
    if any(dcol in col for dcol in cols_diff):
        print(col)
This code will iterate through table_cols_lookup and print col if any of the elements in cols_diff are found in col.

Comment: @Kwright02 make that an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single loop (or comprehension) to extract all the column names and create a `dict`, then any particular column can be searched for in linear time.

```py
import re
cols = {re.search(r'\[(\w+)]', s).group(1) : s for s in table_cols_lookup}
cols_diff = ['VendorPartNumber']
for c in cols_diff:
    print(cols.get(c, 'Not Found'))
```

Comment: This doesn't work because it returns only the column name, but not the value from the look up list. 

The value I need to be returned is `[VendorPartNumber] NVARCHAR(MAX)` - which would be an object in the `table_cols_lookup`

Comment: @mcbdx Then use a `dict` instead of a `set`. See my updated answer.